# show shortcodes in editor

Tags: shortcode, editor

Is there any way in which i can show custom shortcodes inside the editor panel, I have a bunch that I've created and thought it would be a good idea?

Not found anything online other than tutorials on how to create them - which I already know.

Thanks

Comment: Have you look at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4303/styling-shortcodes-in-visual-editor?rq=1 ?

Comment: normally how shortcode work first thing is this  so  create a function and creat its short code by  add_shortcode('shortcode','functionname')  you can get  detail on wordpress codex for this after that  you can call the shortcode  in this  [shortcode]  or if  you want to call it in template then use do_shortcode([shortcode]);

Answer (score -1):

Having stumbled across this (really late), here is the [answer as posted on the wordpress forum by MichaelH](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-list-all-active-shortcodes):

```
<?php
global $shortcode_tags;
echo "<pre>"; print_r($shortcode_tags); echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Putting it here so anyone searching here might find it.